# Does accuracy lower for higher level weapons?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I came across a level 15 axe with really high damage (I am 12), and while in the first game, over-leveled weapons could not be equipped, in this one they can, granted you have the associated stat high enough (strength in this case).

However, it seems that it's greatly reduced my ability to hit enemies, with the weapon itself and skills associated with it. There's no indicator on the weapon that this is the case, am I just unlucky or do over-leveled weapons actually lower your accuracy when using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yesterday I was playing with my friend who managed to get a 2H axe 3 level above his own and he got -60% accuracy. Later he got another one 1 level above and I got a dagger for my rogue 1 level above and while he had -20% accuracy I only had -10%. So the formula should be:

- 1H weapon: -10% accuracy for each weapon level above your own
- 2H weapon: -20% accuracy for each weapon level above your own

Comment: Mine was a 2H Axe at 35%

Comment: @n_palum 35% accuracy loss or remaining? Any accuracy bonus on the axe?

Comment: 35% chance to hit remaining. No bonuses on the axe. Level 12 Fane, axe was level 15

Comment: basic accuracy is usually 95% so a malus of 60%. My formula seems correct -20% * 3 level above. I will change my formula to be more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no indicator on the weapon, but yes, your second thought is correct.

Equipping a weapon with a level higher than your character level will result in decreased weapon accuracy (at least 20%) until you meet the level requirements.

There is no current penalty for equipping armor or jewelry of a higher level requirement.

Comment: Is it 20% per level you are under? It seemed to usually be 35% accuracy for being 3 levels under on the axe.

Comment: There's some discussion on this on reddit currently - it's either totally dependent on level or there are different penalties based on whether it's a one-handed or two-handed weapon. I've only experienced the 20% loss while equipping Lord Withermoore's spear, myself.

Link:
https://www.reddit.com/r/DivinityOriginalSin/comments/75aq4s/psa_too_high_level_weapons_reduce_accuracy/